# R and shell in macOS Catalina

Tags: command-line, shell, zsh, r

I just got a new M1 mac with macOS Catalina at my workplace, and I'm having trouble when running R from the command line (actually, when running it from a Makefile). I'm relatively new to the shell so there's probably something I'm missing here.

I want to run R projects using a Makefile. I installed R 3.6 using a downloaded package, and while it does run when I type `R` in the Terminal, it does not when I write a Makefile that calls `R CMD BATCH scr.R`.

The only thing I know is that it seems to be using different shells. While the terminal uses zsh (`echo ${SHELL}` gives `/bin/zsh`), when I run it through a Makefile, it uses `/bin/sh`, which points to bash: `sh --version` > `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release ...`.

I tried installing R with homebrew and it did work, but it's not my ideal solution because a) I want R 3.6 and getting previous versions in homebrew is a bit of a headache, and b) I don't want to install the packages twice.

I also tried changing the `/bin/sh` symlink so it points to `/bin/zsh`, but it didn't work either.

Even if I add `SHELL := zsh` at the beginning fo the Makefile, I still get a similar error: `zsh:1: command not found: R.`

So my question is: what is exactly going on here? Why do I get a different output when using the Terminal than when calling the commands via a Make? And how can I fix this?

Thanks.

P.S. I forgot to mention. The "normal" R installation from CRAN works on the Terminal because I added an alias to `.zshrc`. But the shell that runs with Make doesn't seem to read this config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI, I solved by adding the R home address (find it typing `R.home()` in `R`) to the PATH. This should work:

```
sudo echo "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources" >> /etc/paths
```